# Why am I getting an invalid URL on this stimulus controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I am trying to dynamically load form partials based on a select dropdown change. I am getting an error though stating failed to construct URL, invalid URL. I'm not really sure what this is looking for. Logging the URL to console shows this: /scheduleevents/select

Can anyone help me out?

Error:

```
stimulus.js? [sm]:1678 Error invoking action "change->remote-select#update"

TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

Console Log value:

```
/scheduleevents/select
```

scheduleevent form:

```
<select data-controller="remote-select" 
        data-remote-select-url-value="<%= scheduleevents_select_path %>" 
        data-remote-select-name-value="form[occurrence]" 
        data-action="change->remote-select#update">
        <%= Scheduleevent.occurrences.each do |occurrence| %>
          <option value="<%= occurrence.second %>"><%= occurrence.first %></option>
        <% end %>
</select>
```

remote_select_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static values = {
    url: String,
    name: String,
  }

connect() {
    console.log("Connected to controller.");
    this.element.setAttribute('data-action', 'change->remote-select#update');
  }

  update() {
    console.log(this.urlValue);
    const url = new URL(this.urlValue);
    
    url.searchParams.append(this.nameValue, this.element.value);

    Turbo.visit(url, { action: "replace" });
  }
}
```

Route:

```
get 'scheduleevents/select' => 'scheduleevents#select'
```

scheduleevents controller:

```
def select
  @selected = params[:form][:occurrence]
end
```

select partial:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag :section_two %>
  <%= render partial: @selected %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes I have updated the post with the error.

Comment: Updated post with console log.

Comment: That is not a URL, meaning it does not have a host or a protocol. Try this instead, switch `scheduleevents_select_path` to `scheduleevents_select_url` to get the full URL.